# Change ImageButton's Image programmatically

Tags: android, png, imagebutton

I'm working on an app for android. I would to change source image of a ImageButton, but when i use this code:

```
imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.onstate)
```

the image in the app doesn't change and in the debugging window I see the phrase: `I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config`  every time that I click the button.

The onstate image have a .png ext, and I have put this in `drawable` folder of my project. What can I do? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**


I see that the phrase is present also if i delete the class for change the image of imagebutton, then I think that the problem isn't the phrase: `I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config`.

**EDIT #2:**
I've solved using button.invalidate() method. Now all things functions properly.

Comment: Did you try with `setImageDrawable` ?

Comment: Yes, but nothing change. 15 minutes ago I tried with imageButton.invalidate(), now all functions properly.